# civiCase missing relationships to reports and new system category

Tags: civicase

I am getting errors about a missing case relationship to reports:

[error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => exceptionHandler
)

```
[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name_a_b as `name_a_b`, a.label_a_b as `label_a_b`, a.name_b_a as `name_b_a`, a.label_b_a as `label_b_a`, a.description as `description`, a.contact_type_a as `contact_type_a`, a.contact_type_b as `contact_type_b`, a.contact_sub_type_a as `contact_sub_type_a`, a.contact_sub_type_b as `contact_sub_type_b`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37.display_block_on_contact_summary as `custom_157`
```

FROM civicrm_relationship_type a
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_relationship__37` `a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37` ON `a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37`.entity_id = `a`.id
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37.display_block_on_contact_summary' in 'field list']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name_a_b as `name_a_b`, a.label_a_b as `label_a_b`, a.name_b_a as `name_b_a`, a.label_b_a as `label_b_a`, a.description as `description`, a.contact_type_a as `contact_type_a`, a.contact_type_b as `contact_type_b`, a.contact_sub_type_a as `contact_sub_type_a`, a.contact_sub_type_b as `contact_sub_type_b`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37.display_block_on_contact_summary as `custom_157`
FROM civicrm_relationship_type a
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_relationship__37` `a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37` ON `a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37`.entity_id = `a`.id
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37.display_block_on_contact_summary' in 'field list']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name_a_b as `name_a_b`, a.label_a_b as `label_a_b`, a.name_b_a as `name_b_a`, a.label_b_a as `label_b_a`, a.description as `description`, a.contact_type_a as `contact_type_a`, a.contact_type_b as `contact_type_b`, a.contact_sub_type_a as `contact_sub_type_a`, a.contact_sub_type_b as `contact_sub_type_b`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37.display_block_on_contact_summary as `custom_157`
FROM civicrm_relationship_type a
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_relationship__37` `a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37` ON `a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37`.entity_id = `a`.id
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a_to_civicrm_value_relationship__37.display_block_on_contact_summary' in 'field list']"]
)

Answer (score 0):

By "report" I assume you mean a CiviReport? It sounds like you used to have a custom field when the report was created and then the custom field was deleted. You can try recreating/resaving the report.